# Models in arithmetic

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, arithmetic, model-theory

I have to prove that there exists model of complete arithmetic $\bf A$ such that it contains $a\in A$ and $a$ is divisible by all prime numbers. I don't know where to start.

Comment: What sorts of constructions in model theory - especially applications of the compactness theorem- do you already know and understand?

Comment: I know a few examples of applications of the compactness theorem, such as that it doesn't exist a theory which models are all finite comutative groups, or if theory has arbitrarily large finite models, it has an infinite model...

Comment: OK, think about how you prove the latter - you introduce a bunch of new symbols and some additional axioms relating them to each other (namely, a bunch of constant symbols $c_i$ for $i\in\mathbb{N}$ and axioms "$c_i\not=c_j$" for $i\not=j$), and show that (i) the resulting theory has a model and (ii) any model of that theory has the property you want. Do you see how to do something similar here?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to build a set of sentences with property that a is divisible with all prime numbers. If I have this, I know how to do the rest.

Comment: In the example in my previous comment, the construction worked by taking the "big" requirement ("infinitely many different things") and breaking it into a bunch of "small" requirements ("$c_i\not=c_j$"), each of which could be handled by a single sentence. If "every prime divides $a$" is our "big" requirement, what's an example of a corresponding "small" requirement?

Comment: Maybe $\{ a |a_c_i, c_i $ is prime $\}?$

Comment: Basically yes - see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

As developed in the comments, the solution is to first introduce one or more constant symbols standing for the "special" elements we care about, and then break our "big" requirement into many "small" requirements.

In this case, we want to introduce a single constant symbol $c$ to be our thing which is divisible by every prime. Our "big" requirement is "$c$ is divisible by every prime," so our "small" requirements will be each of the sentences "$p$ divides $c$" for $p$ a prime. A bit more precisely, we're looking at the set of sentences $$X=\{\exists x[x\cdot (1+1+...+1\mbox{ ($p$ times}))=c]: p\mbox{ prime}\}.$$ For example, $X$ contains the sentences "$\exists x[x\cdot (1+1)=c]$," "$\exists x[x\cdot (1+1+1+1+1)=c]$," and so forth.

Now consider $TA\cup X$ (where $TA$ is the true theory of arithmetic). It's not hard to show *(exercise)* that $TA\cup X$ is finitely satisfiable; by compactness, that means it has a model. And any $M\models TA\cup X$ - or rather, the *reduct* of any such $M$ to the language of arithmetic (just forget the new constant symbol) - is an example of what we want.